# Replaced & with &amp; W3C validator Still Showing Error

Tags: html, validation, blogger

I'm trying to fix w3 validator based errors on my site but i'm shocked when i see this error

> Error: & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)

I'm using `&amp;` as a replaced tag with `&` in site HTML. So why w3c validator showing errors to replace `&` with `&amp;` because i already done it.

Can anyone help this issue ?

Reference URL: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.urgentfiles.com%2F

Comment: You need to change the URLs and the params too.

Comment: Thanks but I can't change the first one because we've no more access to dynamic css files.

Comment: What dynamic CSS? I don't understand!

Comment: https://www.blogger.com/dyn-css/authorization.css these are locked files used inside blogger and Google add them automatically, we can't remove or replace them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all of those validation errors (from number 6 to 49), the ampersand is not necessary because you are passing a unique parameter.

```
<a href='//www.urgentfiles.com/search/label/Action?max-results=6'>
    Action
</a>
```

In cases with a URL containing two or more parameters, you need a double escape like `&amp;amp;` to correct the issue. For example.

```
<a href='//www.urgentfiles.com/search/label/Action?max-results=6&amp;amp;other-param=demo'>
    Action
</a>
```

Comment: Hey man, Can you fix w3c validator errors for &lt;!--</body>--&gt;
I'm using this code with replacing with </body> tag so it shows 4 errors.
Reference URL:https://html5.validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.urgentfiles.com%2F

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're probably using `&` unescaped in `href` attributes.

> Error: & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &.)
>
> At line 1647, column 65
>
> `bel/Simulation?&max-results=6'`

It's often overlooked, but `&` should also become `&amp;` in all similar locations:

```html
bel/Simulation?&max-results=6
<!-- becomes -->
bel/Simulation?&amp;max-results=6
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the **URLs** and the **parameters** too. Consider two examples:

```
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='https://www.blogger.com/dyn-css/authorization.css?targetBlogID=1668100655847438073&zx=0bb1bf52-b577-4cae-9e5b-60d9a3bd54cf' />
```

Should be replaced with:

```
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='https://www.blogger.com/dyn-css/authorization.css?targetBlogID=1668100655847438073&amp;zx=0bb1bf52-b577-4cae-9e5b-60d9a3bd54cf' />
```

And the next series of ones:

```
<li><a href='http://www.urgentfiles.com/search/label/Action?&max-results=6' title='Action'>Action</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.urgentfiles.com/search/label/Adventure?&max-results=6' title='Adventure'>Adventure</a></li>
```

Should be:

```
<li><a href='http://www.urgentfiles.com/search/label/Action?&amp;max-results=6' title='Action'>Action</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.urgentfiles.com/search/label/Adventure?&amp;max-results=6' title='Adventure'>Adventure</a></li>
```